# Prove that this topological space is Haursdorff and Compact

Tags: general-topology, compactness, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

The following question is from my topology assignment and I was unable to solve it.

> Consider the equivalence relation $\sim$ on $\mathbb{R} \times [0,1] $ defined by  $(x,t) \sim (x+1, t)$, $x\in \mathbb{R}$ and $t\in [0,1]$. Let   $ X= (\mathbb{R} \times [0,1]) / \sim $ be the quotient space. Prove that $X$ is Hausdorff and compact.

I have studied Quotient Space from Wayne Patty but I am not good at solving problems of quotient topology. It is my weak point despite reading the theory a lot of times.

So, it is my very humble request can you please give some hints for this question. I shall be really thankful.

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Have you drawn any pictures?  That helps a lot.

Comment: Note that $(x,t) \sim (x+n, t)$ where $n$ is any integer.

Comment: @ArcticChar I was at loss of intuition for this problem because I am not really good at solving problems of Quotient Topology. It is a weak point of mine.Can you please give some advice.

Comment: If you have no intuition, then work using only the definition. What all the open sets in $X$ by definition? Pick 2 elements $x, y$ in $X$, can you find disjoint open set $U, V$ containing $x, y$ respectively?

Comment: @Arctic Char In X the open sets are : Let P be a set open in $\mathbb{R}$ and Q be open in [0,1] and all open sets are of this form. Then by using product topology $P\times Q$ is open in X. Yes , I can find disjoint open sets P and Q containing X and Y. Also, I have a side question

Comment: @ArcticChar Kindly tell how should I proceed now.